# Lightness order Error (LOE) for images quality assessement - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to implement the LOE measure proposed in the article "Naturalness Preserved Enhancement Algorithm for Non-Uniform Illumination Images"

The algortithm is the following: 
Let I be the original image and Ie the enhanced image. The lightness
**L(x, y)** of  image I is given as the maximum of its three color channels:

> L(x, y) = max Ic(x, y); c∈{r,g,b}

(same for **Le(x,y)**);

Then for each pixel (x, y) we compute **RD(x,y)** defined as:

> RD(x,y) = Sum (Sum( U(L(x, y), L(i, j ))⊕U(Le(x, y), Le(i, j ))))
>
> where i={1..n}; j={1..m}.

**m** and **n** are the size of the image and **U(x,y)=1** if (x>=y ) and 0 elsewise.

Finally

> LOE = sum(sum(RD))/size(I)

In order, to keep computation simple the authors downsample the image with a factor **r = 50 /min(m,n)**.

The results I obtained for the attached image equals to  **467.2846** while it should be around **1.17**. 
I Post my code here:

```
I = imread('birds.jpg'); % original image
Ie = imread('birds_output.jpg'); % enhanced image

[N M n] = size (I);

L = max(I,[],3);
Le = max(Ie,[],3);

r = 50 / min (M,N);
Md = round(M*r);
Nd = round(N*r);
Ld =imresize(L,[Nd Md]);
Led =imresize(Le,[Nd Md]);

RD = zeros (Nd,Md);
size (RD)

for y = 1:Md
    for x = 1:Nd

        E = xor((Ld(x,y)>=Ld(:,:)),(Led(x,y)>=Led(:,:)));
        RD(x,y) = sum(E(:));

    end
end
LOE = sum(RD(:))/(Md*Nd);
```

Also, the images I used:

- [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDaCs.jpg)
- [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M8ET.jpg)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you link a different source or provide all relevant information without a link to the publication? You might not be aware of this since you are in a university network, but publications from IEEE cannot be accessed from private (read: home) networks without purchasing them. Universities usually have a "flat rate".

Comment: the paper can be downloaded from this link https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236675436_Naturalness_Preserved_Enhancement_Algorithm_for_Non-Uniform_Illumination_Images.

Comment: If the link is accessible freely, you can of course add it to your original question. But I doubt that anyone is going to read the paper in order to help you and it is not really relevant too. You could simply state the equation you are trying to implement along with the code you already posted, add your output and the output that you *should* get. It would increase your chances of getting help, that's all.

Comment: I updated my post. THank you for your remarks.